# Где хранить все картинки для игры в phonegap?

Tags: javascript, phonegap

у меня появился простой вопрос, но на его ответ я ничего не нашел в интернете. Дело в том, что я делаю простенькую игру на js, с помощью phonegap. Игра не сложная, и хорошо продвигается. Но в этой игре будет много картинок, и всё бы ничего, но именно картинки забирают больше памяти, максимальный вес приложения для phonegap это 50MB (Бесплатно). Вес apk в google play тоже имеет лимит 50 MB, И из-за картинок приложение не может весить меньше 50MB, потому что их будет много. Прошу у вас помощи, так как не знаю где их хранить, можно ли использовать какие-то хранилища или прочее для картинок? Я бы ее хотел выпустить в гугл плей, но из-за картинок вес превышает 50MB, и phonegap отказывается его превращать в apk. Еще раз скажу что игра простая, и очень хорошо разрабатывается на js, поэтому phonegap для меня это лучший выбор. Благодаю если кто-то ответит и просветит меня :)

Comment: Оффтоп, можно ли в svg хранить картинки?

Comment: Я вас не совсем понимаю...?

Comment: Смотрите, есть два вида формата изображений: растровые (jpg, png, ...) и векторные (svg, ...). В растровых информация о каждом пикселе хранится, а в векторном задаются формулы для рисования. Например, svg это по сути xml с описанием фигур. Правильный svg весит намного меньше чем тот же png и при этом масштабируется без потери качества, т.к.нужно только пересчитать картинки под новый размер

Comment: зачем вам вообще хранить изображения на устройстве? вы же можете запрашивать их, раз работаете с WebView

Comment: Картинки должны быть именно png, Yugofx, запрашивать от куда?